# How to introduce two aggressive dogs to each other?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training

So, in my colony a friend of mine has a German Shephard - Tyson (1.5 years old) and I have a Labrador - Vector (2 years old). They both are aggressive dogs, Tyson especially. But I want to have them both as friends.

Anytime they see each other, they snarl and snap at each other and bark a lot.
Vector is a very friendly dog and is always seen waving his tail around everyone.
Tyson, however, did try to bite me once. I still want them to be friends. Is there a way for this to happen?

Comment: Are they only aggressive with each other or with other dogs, too?

Answer (score 1):

Some dogs will not friends with other dogs and this might be only certain dogs that they will not be friends with. It could take months of one on one training with each of these dogs so with that in mind, it sounds like a bad idea. Trying to get them to be friends could result in a terrible dog fight. Once there is one fight, it dramatically increases the chance that there could be another fight because each dog will have the memory of the fight implanted in their brain.

Answer (score 0):

If they are meeting up in one or the others environment, they may feel the other is a threat and want protect their area or owner. I dont know if the other owner is committed to them be coming friends but maybe introducing them in a neutral area  and you could use muzzles for a brief period so they don't hurt eachother and can get a good feel and smell of eachothers scent. I'm no dog expert and some find muzzled to be mean. I'm just giving you an idea that may or may not work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, and it's not worth it to try.

Like people, dogs have other dogs that they are or -aren't- friends with. It can have to do with their energy levels to doggie manners to memories of other encounters with other dogs. If they act this way when they are afar, you can be sure that getting them closer will result in a dog fight. Keep in mind that once a dog fight starts, it's likely not going to stop on its own, which means that a human has to intervene and it's especially easy to get bit breaking up a dog fight. Dog fights can and have resulted in dead or fatally injured dogs.

There are rules and laws in different countries regarding dogs who have bitten humans, for example, in some places dogs must be surrendered for destruction on their second bite.

If you are absolutely dead set on these dogs becoming friends, I would hire a professional dog trainer to come help you. At their level of violence, and with both dogs being aggressive and one dog nearly having bitten you before, I would not trust the internet or a book or youtube video to help, I really think that you need a professional. It may be that both dogs may need professional rehabilitation and help to become non-aggressive dogs, first.

As you can see from this long reply, this isn't a casual affair. It would be better for passing fancies to be put to rest here.